# How to sort players based on two value in VBScript

Tags: sorting, vbscript

In my program I would like to sort players based on two values (score and previous rank) I have manage to sort based on just there score..

I would like to reorder if one or more player have the same score but the player with the lowest previous rank should display first.

```
dim mPlayer(30)

Class Player
    dim score
    dim name
    dim lowestRank
End Class

dim sorted, i
dim tempPlayer
Set tempPlayer = New Player
sorted = False
Do Until sorted
    sorted = True
    For i = 0 To mNumPlayers - 2
        If (mPlayer(i + 1).score > mPlayer(i).score) Then
            ' swap
            sorted = False
            Call CopytempPlayerData(tempPlayer, mPlayer(i))
            Call CopytempPlayerData(mPlayer(i), mPlayer(i + 1))
            Call CopytempPlayerData(mPlayer(i + 1), tempPlayer)
        End If
    Next
Loop

Set temptempPlayer = Nothing
lstPlayers.Clear()

For i = 0 To mPlayer - 1
   lstPlayers.Items.add(mPlayer(i).name)
Next
```

Comment: Try sorting by `100000 * mPlayer(i).score ± mPlayer(i).lowestRank` rather than by bare `mPlayer(i).score` where substitute `100000` with maximal `score` value. However, take a look at [Sorting Algorithms](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Sorting_Algorithms)…

Comment: There is no Max score. I will try mPlayer(i).score ± mPlayer(i).lowestRank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [If...Then...Else Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9(v=vs.84).aspx) documentation. Syntax:

> ```
> ' Block syntax: 
> If condition Then
>    [statements]
> [ElseIf condition-n Then
>    [elseifstatements]] . . .
> [Else
>    [elsestatements]]
> End If 
>
> Single-Line syntax:
> If condition Then statements [Else elsestatements ]
> ```

Apply to your circumstances as follows:

```
    If (mPlayer(i + 1).score > mPlayer(i).score) Then
        ' swap
        sorted = False
        Call CopytempPlayerData(tempPlayer, mPlayer(i))
        Call CopytempPlayerData(mPlayer(i), mPlayer(i + 1))
        Call CopytempPlayerData(mPlayer(i + 1), tempPlayer)
    Else If (mPlayer(i + 1).score = mPlayer(i).score) Then
        ''' not sure about Comparison Operator in next condition
        If (mPlayer(i + 1).lowestRank < mPlayer(i).lowestRank) Then
          ' swap
          sorted = False
          Call CopytempPlayerData(tempPlayer, mPlayer(i))
          Call CopytempPlayerData(mPlayer(i), mPlayer(i + 1))
          Call CopytempPlayerData(mPlayer(i + 1), tempPlayer)            
        End If
    End If
```

or use a  [`Sub` procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx9ceb2w(v=vs.84).aspx) as follows (having in mind [Local Variables in Sub Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt223ahx(v=vs.84).aspx)):

```
    If (mPlayer(i + 1).score > mPlayer(i).score) Then
        swapPlayers
    Else If (mPlayer(i + 1).score = mPlayer(i).score) Then
        ''' not sure about Comparison Operator in next condition
        If (mPlayer(i + 1).lowestRank < mPlayer(i).lowestRank) Then
            swapPlayers
        End If
    End If

' remaining script statements here

Sub swapPlayers
        ' swap
        sorted = False
        Call CopytempPlayerData(tempPlayer, mPlayer(i))
        Call CopytempPlayerData(mPlayer(i), mPlayer(i + 1))
        Call CopytempPlayerData(mPlayer(i + 1), tempPlayer)
End Sub
```